# Excel inputbox how many copies to print with max number

Tags: vba, excel

I need a inputbox to ask how many copies to print with a max number allowed to be enter.

I have the below code but which works but if i enter more than "1" it triggers the
`If NumberOfCopies >= "11" Then` and if i click the cancel button it also triggers the same thing

```
'ASKS HOW MANY COPIES TO PRINT
PRINTS:
Dim NumberOfCopies As String
NumberOfCopies = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want to print? Must enter 0-10", Type:=2)

If NumberOfCopies >= "11" Then
MsgBox "Max to print is 10 copies"
GoTo PRINTS
End If

If NumberOfCopies = "0" Or NumberOfCopies = "" Then
'do not print
Else
ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=NumberOfCopies
End If
```

Comment: cint(NumberOfCopies)>=11

Comment: When I run it the way you have it, it evaluates correctly.  Entering 1 in the input box moves past the if statement as "1" < "11".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still need to test for the user hitting Cancel...This worked for me when hitting Cancel, or typing in 0, 1, or 11

```
Prints:
Dim NumberOfCopies As String
NumberOfCopies = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want to print? Must enter 0-10", Type:=2)

If NumberOfCopies = "False" Or NumberOfCopies = "0" Then
  'If user hits Cancel, NumberofCopies will be "False"
Else
  If NumberOfCopies >= "11" Then
    MsgBox "Max to print is 10 copies"
    GoTo Prints
  Else
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=NumberOfCopies
  End If
End If
```

Comment: I removed the quotation marks on `If NumberOfCopies >= "11" Then`

 and chanced `If NumberOfCopies = "False" Or NumberOfCopies = "0" Then`

 to `If NumberOfCopies = "False" Or NumberOfCopies = "0" Or NumberOfCopies = "" Then` so if user clicks ok when input box is empty it does the same thing as entering 0. and it seems to work thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Putting numbers in quotation marks turns them into a String. Since you want the user to input a number, you should make the following changes:

```
    Dim NumberOfCopies As Int
NumberOfCopies = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want to print Must enter 0-10", Type:=1)

If NumberofCopies >= 11 Then
...

If NumberOfCopies = 0 or NumberOfCopies = "" Then
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`Type:=2` is actually for Text type. You are working with numbers, so you should set it as `Type:=1`. With that, if the user enters anything that is not a number, it will automatically pop up a message "Number is not valid" (no scripting effort required for that).

You should also avoid using Position labels whenever you can. Your code could be easily scripted with `Do...While` loops.

As already pointed out, when working with numbers, do not use them enclosed in double quotes, or VBA will treat them as String (which is not what you want).

@Rdster brought a good point for when user hits "Cancel" button. When that occurs, the value of your variable will be "False"(a String), so you should look for that either.

With all of that being said, I believe your code would work better like this:

```
'ASKS HOW MANY COPIES TO PRINT
Dim NumberOfCopies As String
Do
    NumberOfCopies = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want to print? Must enter 0-10", Type:=1)
    If NumberOfCopies = "False" Then Exit Sub   ' If user clicks on Cancel button
    If NumberOfCopies > 10 Then
        MsgBox "Max to print is 10 copies"
    End If
Loop While NumberOfCopies > 10    'although producing the same result, it is cleaner to compare with 10, than to >=11

'Avoid leaving blank conditions. Work with what you have.
'Everything that doesn't match your conditions will be skipped anyways.
If NumberOfCopies > 0 And NumberOfCopies < 10 Then
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=NumberOfCopies
End If
```